# Границы муниципальных образований России yandex api

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

я ищу границы МО России.
Есть ли подобное для муниципальных образований целиком и по отдельности по регионам и муниципалитетам?
Хочу построить такую [карту](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/96/%D0%9A%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC_%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%A4%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B0%2C_2010.png?uselang=ru)
Это для регионов из этого [примера](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/regions_districts)

```
ymaps.borders.load('RU', {
        lang: 'ru',
        quality: 2
    })
```

Для этого пример у меня дополнительный вопрос есть: как сделать так, чтобы эта карта в окне появилась полностью (или другими словами как сделать персональные лимиты для zoom out)? В этом примере не вся Россия попадает сразу на окне: либо Калининград или Камчатка не видны. Приходится left-click-and-drag, чтобы увидеть остальную часть.

Answer (score 0):

В API Яндекс.Карт не получится получить границы уровня меньше, чем [регионы](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/dg/concepts/regions.html/?from=club).

Скачать контуры интересующих вас границ можно на сторонних сервисах, например http://data.esosedi.org